# Como enviar dados selecionados para um servidor ftp

Tags: c#, sql

Estou a desenvolver um projeto em c# e neste momento tenho de selecionar uma linha de um DataGridView que eu criei, criar um ficheiro de texto com esses dados e enviar o ficheiro criado para um servidor ftp. Já fiz uma pesquisa, mas não consegui encontrar nada que me fosse util.Se quiserem algum codigo ou alguma screenshot do meu projeto eu posso disponibilizar.
Este é o codigo da DataGridView:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data source = **** ; Database=**** ; User Id=****; Password=*****");
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TransDocument, TransSerial, TransDocNumber, PartyName, PartyLocalityID, TotalAmount, ShipToPostalCode FROM dbo.UXMenu WHERE Estado = 0", myConnection);
objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
dataGridViewEnviarDados.DataSource = dt;
dataGridViewEnviarDados.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

UPDATE:

Estou a utiliza este codigo:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://123.321.123" + arquivo.Name);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "password");
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(arquivo.FullName);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
MessageBox.Show("Arquivo " + arquivo.Name + " foi enviado com sucesso. " + response.StatusDescription);
response.Close();`
```

Mas tenho este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, servidor FTP = `File Transfer Protocol` ou `Protocolo de Transferência de Arquivo`. Não tem como você enviar dados pro servidor FTP, tem como enviar arquivos, qual seria sua real necessidade ? o que já tem pronto ?

Comment: Vou editar a pesqunta para explicar melhor. Eu quero selecionar a linha e escrever os dados dessa linha num ficheiro de texto e enviar esse ficheiro de texto para o ftp. já tenho a datagridview toda pronta so falta a parte de criar o ficheiro de texto com os dados selecionados e enviar para o ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passo a passo:

1- Verifica se há linhas selecionadas no grid.

2- Percorre as linhas selecionadas uma a uma.

2.1 - Gera o arquivo de texto, e escreve nele com a classe `TextWriter` percorrendo cada coluna do grid, e separando os campos com um `;`

2.2 - Fecha o objeto `TextWriter`

2.3 - Utiliza a classe `FtpWebRequest` junto a um `Stream` para enviar o arquivo ao servidor FTP.

Segue código:

```
    private void buttonEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo("C:\\arquivoDeTexto_"+r.Index+".txt");

                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(arquivo.FullName, false, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    {
                        tw.Write(r.Cells[c.Name].Value.ToString()+";");
                    }

                    tw.Close();
                }

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://seuservidorftp.com/"+ arquivo.Name);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "senha");

                StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(arquivo.FullName);
                byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                sourceStream.Close();
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo " + arquivo.Name + " foi enviado com sucesso. " + response.StatusDescription);

                response.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, marquei como resposta

Comment: tenho uma questao, o `ftp://seuservidorftp.com/"` como eu obtenho o meu servidor como esta no exemplo? O meu servidor é assim : 123.12.321 é so colar por cima ou tenho de fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: se 123.12.321 é seu endereço ip... sim, só colocar `ftp://123.12.321` (está faltando uma parte para ser um ip válido né) rs

Comment: O 123.12.321 era um exemplo. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Tem como eu meter o nome do ficheiro criado com o que da dentro das colunas "TransDocNumber"?

Comment: o caminho do arquivo está errado... sobre o nome do arquivo usar o valor de uma das colunas, basta fazer assim: `r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` e o caminho do arquivo no FTP deve ser: `"ftp://123.321.123/" + arquivo.Name` está faltando a barra para separar o servidor do nome do arquivo

Comment: Deste jeito  `FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://123.321.123/" + r.Cells[0].Value.ToString());` ?

Comment: nao da para juntar as 3 primeiras colunas? Precisava que o nome dio ficheiro fosse TransDocument + TransSerial + TransDocNumber

Comment: dá sim, basta concatenar.... `r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + r.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` você também pode usar o Name da coluna, se souber... `r.Cells["colunaX"].Value.ToString()`

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado

Comment: Posso so fazer mais uma questão?

Comment: Eu depois de enviar tenho de retirar a linha enviada da datagridview e eu tou a mostrar na datagridview assim ` SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TransDocument, TransSerial, TransDocNumber, PartyName, PartyLocalityID, TotalAmount, ShipToPostalCode FROM dbo.UXMenu WHERE Estado = 0", myConnection);` e necessitava de fazer um update à linha selecionada para mudar o Estado para 1 e assim ela saia, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64428/discussion-between-josue-figueiredo-and-rovann-linhalis).

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class EnvioFtp
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Atributo para lib
        /// </summary>
        private FtpWebRequest FtpClient { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Atribui valores iniciais para envio e conexão
        /// </summary>
        private void ConectaFtp()
        {
            this.FtpClient = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://endereco.com/teste.txt");
            this.FtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "senha");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Realiza envio, utilizando o atributo já iniciado(FtpClient)
        /// </summary>
        public void EnviaProjetoFtp()
        {

            this.ConectaFtp();
            FileInfo arquivoInfo = new FileInfo("teste.txt");
            this.FtpClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            this.FtpClient.UseBinary = true;
            this.FtpClient.ContentLength = arquivoInfo.Length;

            using (FileStream fs = arquivoInfo.OpenRead())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesSent = 0;
                int bytes = 0;

                using (Stream stream = this.FtpClient.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    while (bytesSent < arquivoInfo.Length)
                    {
                        bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        bytesSent += bytes;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar

Comment: Para eu conseguir utilizar esse codigo necessito que ele envie a linha selecionada da datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Este exemplo mostra como carregar um arquivo em um servidor FTP.
Exemplo
C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Se ajudou, marque a resposta, por favor. :)